# The specified deps.json [] does not exist - Blazor WebAssembly App project type

Tags: .net-core, nuget, blazor, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I have seen similar posts to this but I have not been able to get a solution to make this work.

I spin up a new app and try any ef command and I get this message. I've never gotten this before in any version of VS and I have not found any real solutions to fix it.

I've deleted the bin and obj folders, updated VS, tried copying files to root, restarted my machine after updating.

**The specified deps.json [] does not exist**

I'm on VS2019 16.10.1  NET Core 5.0

Scaffold-DbContext that has worked in the past is not working at all now.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=servername;User Id=sa;Password=argh;Database=arghdb" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir Context -OutputDir Models
```

Not sure what to do right now. This is crippling.

Please describe the issue in 2-3 sentences. Include what you're trying to accomplish when the issue occurs.

I am trying to scaffold a database in ef core within a blazor project.

When did it begin and how often does it occur?
Every time migrations/scaffolding is tried in a blazor project

What errors do you see?

The specified deps.json [...bin\Debug\net5.0\CourtFilings.Web.deps.json] does not exist

What's the environment and are there recent changes?
No recent changes. Just updates to VS2019

What have you tried to troubleshoot this?
I tried setting the startup project. I have not found another option.

This is what I try that does not work

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=server;User Id=sa;Password=password;Database=database;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir Context -OutputDir Models -Tables CourtFilings  -startupproject CourtFilings.Web

This does work in an ASP.net core web project. Just not Blazor. This has worked in a previous Blazor project.

Answer (score 10):

Change your startup project to the project containing your context rather than the Web.Client app during scaffolding

Answer (score 1):

Well. This appears to only be happening only with the Blazor WebAssembly App project type.

I just tried this on an new ASP.NET Core Web App and I didn't have the problem.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Does anyone know why this is only happening with the Blazor project type?

Comment: Your WebAssembly project couldn't possibly connect to a SQL Server database, with or without this error.  The error message doesn't seem terribly useful, but what you had been trying to accomplish is a non-starter for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Just for those who have a similar problem regarding "`The specified deps.json does not exist`". I had problem with adding scaffold item Razor Page in Rider.  I followed multiple solutions such as :

- Cleaning and rebuilding project
- Adding IDE to OS path variable
- Setting Startup Project
- Adding MyProjectName.spec.json file manually (it causes another MyProjectName.runtimeconfig.json missing, maybe manually borrowing those two files from a working project works though)

But they didn't work. For me Instead of using IDE (mine is Rider) for project creation, I used `Dotnet-CLI` command such as

```
Dotnet new Blazor -o BlazorApp1
```

And it worked. I hope this helps, especially if you are using `Rider` which there is a [reported bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-97724) but it's not resolved yet